# Nothing happens when i bind data in my show.blade.php page

Tags: laravel, data-binding

When i bind data on my frontend i don't get anything and there is no bug or something like please help. Here the tables structures

class CreateResponesTable

```
    Schema::create('respones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();

        $table->longText('text_answer')->unique();

        $table->string('author_name');

        $table->dateTime('lock')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

the table of relations with respones
class AddRelationshipFieldsToResponesTable

```
public function up() 
{
    Schema::table('respones', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');

        $table->foreign('category_id', 'category_fk_851021')->references('id')->on('categories');

        $table->unsignedInteger('author_email_id');

        $table->foreign('author_email_id', 'author_email_fk_851023')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->unsignedInteger('ask_question_id');

        $table->foreign('ask_question_id', 'ask_question_fk_851048')->references('id')->on('ask_questions');
    });
}
```

Here the model of respone
Respone.php

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Respone::Observe(new \App\Observers\ResponeObserver );

}


public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}

public function author_email()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_email_id');
}

public function ask_question()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AskQuestion::class, 'ask_question_id');
}

public function notation(){

    return $this->belongsToMany(Notation::class)->withPivot('rating');

}
```

Here the blade file where i bind data of a response
Show.blade.php

```
               <div class="card-body">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Thématique') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ optional($respone->category)->name }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Nom auteur') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                @if($respone->author_name)
                                    {{ $respone->author_name }}
                                @endif
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Auteur email') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ optional($respone->author_email)->email }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Question') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ optional($respone->ask_question)->text_question }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {{ trans('Réponse') }}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{ $respone->text_answer ?? 'Default' }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

here the model of askQuestion
askQuestion.php

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    AskQuestion::Observe(new \App\Observers\AskQuestionObserver );

    static::addGlobalScope(new CollaborateurScope);
}

/**
* In this method may be it should belongsto instead of hasmany
*/
public function respones()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Respone::class, 'ask_question_id', 'id');
}

public function assigned_to_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'assigned_to_user_id');
}
```

The backend controller

public function show(Respone $respone)

{ abort_if(Gate::denies('respone_show'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

```
    $respone->load('category', 'author_email', 'ask_question');

    return view('admin.respones.show', compact('respone'));
}
```

the frontend controller

```
/**
 * Display the new response done to a question
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Respone $respone, Category $category, User $user,AskQuestion $ask_question)
{
    $respone->load('author_email', 'category', 'ask_question');

    $ask_question->load('Respones');

    return view('respones.show', compact('respone', 'ask_question'));
}
```

Comment: Please show controller which is returning the view

Comment: Okay i'm adding it in my post

Comment: Is the table `responses` or `respones` ?

Comment: It's respones @thisiskelvin